# Microsoft SQL Query to identify records that have not been created yet

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm struggling to explain this, so I apologize in advance. I have one table in Microsoft SQL db that contains duplicate records. At some point every duplicate record, should contain at least 1 row where Column C has a value of Yes.

How can I query for records that don't exist yet?

Table t:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | Cat      | No       |
| 2        | Cat      | No       |
| 3        | Cat      | No       |
| 4        | Dog      | Yes      |
| 5        | Dog      | No       |
| 6        | Fox      | No       |
| 7        | Fox      | No       |
```

The expected output looks like:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C    |
| -------- | -------- | --------    |
| 1        | Cat      | Missing Yes |
| 2        | Fox      | Missing Yes |
```

I tried using `NOT IN` based on examples I found online, but it did not return the desired results.

```
SELECT Column B
FROM t
WHERE Column C NOT IN
(SELECT Column B
 FROM t
 WHERE Column C = 'Yes'
 )
```

Comment: for clarity, you don't care about Column A, it's just a row index? you want a distinct list of values appearing in Column B where those values don't have at least one 'Yes' in column C?

Comment: Hi, Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with an common table expression

```
  WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
  FROM t
)

SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, 'Missing Yes' as ColumnC
FROM cte
GROUP BY ColumnB
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnC = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Wouldn't this do the same without the CTE and just using `FROM t` in the main query?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I think I'm too new to give you a upvote.

Comment: So, why not do everyone a favor and improve your answer?

Comment: It seems that the solution provided is exactly what OP was trying to achieve. Therefore, there is no need to edit or simplify the query.

Comment: The solution provided claims that a CTE is needed or helps to solve the issue, but it only complicates things and does not add any value. That makes this a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already accepted an answer for this, but if you just want a distinct list of the Column B values that don't have a YES then this might be an alternate solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(ColumnA int,ColumnB varchar(10),ColumnC varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(1,'Cat','No'),
(2,'Cat','No'),
(3,'Cat','No'),
(4,'Dog','Yes'),
(5,'Dog','No'),
(6,'Fox','No'),
(7,'Fox','No'),
(8,'Dog','No')


SELECT ColumnB, 'Missing Yes' ColumnC
FROM #tmp t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tmp t2 WHERE t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB and t2.ColumnC = 'YES')
GROUP BY ColumnB
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```